# What are the techniques/fighting styles displayed in Bleach?

Tags: bleach

In the series, a number of different styles are shown among the different characters. Some fight using their Zanpakutō, others use Kidō. Do all of these derived from a similar source? Are there other fighting styles? Can they be combine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are four fighting styles a Shinigami uses are:

1. [Zanjutsu](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Zanjutsu) (Weapon arts) --
   The art of using their weapon to it's full potential.
2. [Hakuda](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Hakuda) (Martial arts) --
   The art of physical power and melee fighting skills.
3. [Hohou](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Hoh%C5%8D) (Movement arts) --
   The art of moving, dodging, and countering.
4. [Kidou](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Kid%C5%8D) (Magic arts) --
   The art of using spells and magic.

They are often used in combination with one another in battle.

Comment: A more "natural" classification: Martial arts and Movement arts (internal physical), Magic arts (internal spiritual), Weapon arts (external physical). What's missing is "external spiritual", which includes manipulating to spirit of weapons (e.g. releasing Zanpakuto) or absorbing spirit energy from the surroundings like Quincies.

Answer (score -2):

1. Zanjutsu: Sword Arts
2. Kido: Magic Arts
3. Hakudo: Martial Arts
4. Hoho  Movement Arts

Each of these is an aspect of shinigami combat, Zanpakuto, Magic, Martial Arts & Movement.

Kido is also divided into 3 parts: Hado (way of destruction), Kaido (way of healing), and Bakudo (way of binding).

Comment: This would answer the questions but it doesn't add anything new that existing answers don't already cover.